# Google Maps view generating huge number of Firebase DB read operations

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore DB to store map markers + metadata for my Google Maps API-based app. When my userbase zooms/pans around the map, they generate a huge amount of Firebase DB read operations.  About 100k read ops per day.  This will be very expensive once I launch the app.  Should I be caching?  Using a KML? What tools or programmatic approaches can I use to cut down on those read ops?

Comment: Caching enabled by default. Unless you disabled it, your queries are already pulling documents from cache to avoid reads from the server. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Answer (score 0):

Avoid executing any Firebase related code in Listeners

because the code you that  have written will be executed all time while user reacts on it

I guess that the reason for you being charged

Comment: Possibly.  When the user pans/zooms the map, the firebase query is run again.  We did this because it's a shared map with lots of users and will change dynamically (why we didn't just do a daily KML/KMZ for the map markers).

Answer (score 0):

consider adding a sync adapter (https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter) as a local cache for the data.